# how to host a Tcp server made in python

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, server

how do I host a Tcp server for free? I have already tried YouTube but nothing seems to work. all the code  in the server is working but it doesn't seem to was to run online.

Answer (score 0):

Is your server running on a network IP address, or on localhost? This sounds like an issue I was having when trying to connect my Raspberry Pi to a server on another computer using websockets. The issue I was having was that because the server was running localhost, no one outside that particular computer could see it, even though all the relevant ports were open. I had to change to use the IP address on my internal network.

Also, you'll want to make sure you have CORS support installed. Many servers block outside connections by default for security reasons, because of cross-origin script attacks. And naturally, make sure the port is open.